# Highcharts - hide dataLabels leaders

Tags: highcharts

I have a pie chart which, potentially, will have empty categories when the page loads as data is dynamic from an SQL database.

I've set up the formatter so that no label is shown if the value is 0, but how does one prevent the leader lines from showing?

I would prefer to avoid the solution of not including the category at all, as it is important to still show it as a possibility in the key

[image]

Comment: Lesson learned: if anything at all is returned for a point by the formatter, the leader is drawn. No return value means no leader!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the data array to plot only values greater than zero:

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    data: [0, 0, 5, 0, 20, 0, 15].filter(function(y) {
        return y > 0
    })
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g98uaoy0/

Or set the right condition in the `formatter` function:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
            if (this.y) {
                return this.y
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mft83dgb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: I am a fool - Part 2 is the answer. I had an else condition in my formatter returning "" which caused it to plot the line... Your first solution also looks neat but I think my data is too complex (each has a custom defined colour and tooltip to display, fed in via JSON)